# Android Development -- AlertDialog showing inside of Tab Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, tabs, alert

I'm having trouble getting an alert dialog to show inside of a Tab Activity. My app will force close every time I try and get the alert dialog to show. My code is as follows:

```
public class TablesActivity extends ListActivity {

final int INFO_ID = 0;
final int STATUS_ID = 1;
AlertDialog alert = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to mark table as dirty?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table Marked Dirty",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    alert = builder.create();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.history,
            TABLES));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {


            alert.show();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

    });
}

static final String[] TABLES = new String[] { "Table 1", "Table 2",
        "Table 3", "Table 4", "Table 5", "Table 6", "Table 7", "Table 8",
        "Table 9", "Table 10", "Table 11", "Table 12", "Table 13"

};

}
```

The problem is arising when I attempt to perform the dialog.show(), and nowhere else. I am getting the logcat error of:

04-16 17:25:15.519: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(311): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44f08320 is not valid; is your activity running?

The error is originating from the dialog.show() line. I am not sure what exactly to do here. The activity is running, after being started earlier by an ActivityGroup spawned by the TabHost.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this problem? I'm at my wits end.

Comment: Resolved my own issue. Replaced (this) with getParent(), AlertDialogs and Activity Groups do not get along.

Comment: Yes. I discovered if the content of a Tab is an Activity then you need to pass the context of the TabActivity to things like alert dialogs rather than the content activity's context.

Comment: You are right.this solved my issue also. Thanks for sharing the knowledge

Answer (score 4):

please use

```
`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getParent());`
```

insted of

```
`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`
```